# How to append submitted form data?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I am looking to append the submitted form data with the most recent form data on top. Before I added the CSS the form data was appending nicely in order but on the right side.I would like to append in  the middle with the nice border. Here is the PHP and CSS. Now it appears somewhat in the center with the nice border, but the text appears on top on the previous submitted form text.

```
<?php 

session_start();




?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Explore</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/pure/0.6.0/pure-min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

 <link id="page_favicon" href="favicon.ico" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" />
 <!-- Optional theme -->
 <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.2-rc.1/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.2-rc.1/js/select2.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="ddslick.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/40036711/Scripts/ddslick.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="searchlist/src/jquery-customselect.js"> </script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="searchlist/src/jquery-customselect.css">
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="timeago.js"></script>



 <!-- GOOGLE API IMPORTANT -->

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">


</head>

<body>
  <ol class="breadcrumb" style="position: fixed; width:100%; z-index: 1000;">
    <li><a href="index.php">  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home" aria-hidden="true"></span> Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="vtsearch.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-credit-card" aria-hidden="true"></span> Hokie Passport</a></li>
    <li><a href="imageSearch.html"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture" aria-hidden="true"></span> Photos</a></li>
    <li><a href="weather.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe" aria-hidden="true"></span> Weather</a></li>

  </ol>


  <div id="allContent" >
    <div id="formData" >
      <input class="button-warning pure-button" style ="position: fixed; bottom: 0px;"title="Clear page content"type="submit" name="clear" id="clearbtn" value="Clear">

      <?php
#FOR THE DRIVERS ONLY 

      if (!isset($_SESSION['inputs'])) {
        // initialize the saved input session variable the first time

        $_SESSION['inputs'] = array();
      }
      if (isset($_POST['name']) || isset($_POST['nameTwo'])) {
        array_push($_SESSION['inputs'], $_POST);

      }
      foreach (array_reverse($_SESSION['inputs']) as $input) {
        if(isset($input['desiredNum']))
        {
          echo "  <span class='trip'> <p class='driverAlert' > DRIVER </p> <img src='taxi.png'  width ='50' height='50'title='driver'> {$input['name']}, Age: {$input['age']} <br> To: {$input['arriveLoc']} - From: {$input['departLoc']}<br>
          Leaves: {$input['departDate']} Returns: {$input['returnDate']} <br> Will drive up to: {$input['desiredNum']} people
          <br> Contact @ {$input['email']} <br> <br> </span> 
          ";
        }

        else
        {
         echo " <span class='trip'> <p class='riderAlert' > PASSENGER </p> <img src='rider.png'  width ='50' height='50'title='rider'> {$input['nameTwo']}, Age: {$input['ageTwo']} <br> Would like to go to {$input['departLocTwo']} from {$input['arriveLocTwo']} on {$input['departDateTwo']} and return on 
         {$input['returnDateTwo']} <br>  Contact @ {$input['emailTwo']}  <br> <br></span> 
         ";
       }

     }


     ?>

   </div>
   <!--  States selector  -->




   <div id="rider">
    <input  class="button-success pure-button" type="button" id="riderbtn"value="Passenger"> <br>
    <form action="vt.php" id="riderForm" method="post" class="form-inline">

      <div class="form-group">
       <input required type="text" class="form-control input-sm"  required id="nameTwo" name="nameTwo" placeholder="Enter Name" autocomplete="off">
     </div><br> <br>

     <div class="form-group">   
       <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="ageTwo" required  name="ageTwo" placeholder="Enter Age" autocomplete="off">
     </div> <br> <br>

     <div class="form-group">

       <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="departLocTwo" required  name="departLocTwo" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Departure Location">
     </div><br> <br>

     <div class="form-group">

       <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="arriveLocTwo" required  name="arriveLocTwo" autocomplete="off"placeholder="Destination Location">
     </div><br> <br>

     <div class="form-group">

       <input type="date" class="form-control input-sm" id="departDateTwo" required  name="departDateTwo" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Depart Date">
     </div><br> <br>

     <div class="form-group">

       <input type="date" class="form-control input-sm" id="returnDateTwo" required  name="returnDateTwo" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Return Date">
     </div> <br> <br>
     <div class="form-group">

       <input type="email" class="form-control input-sm" id="emailTwo" required  name="emailTwo" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Email">
     </div><br> <br>

     <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="submitRider();"> 
   </form>
 </div>


 <div id="driver">
  <input type="button" class="button-success pure-button"  id="driverbtn"value="Driver">

  <form action="vt.php" id="driverForm" method="post" class="form-inline">
    <select class="form-control" id="desiredNum" name="desiredNum">
      <option disabled>How many people may you drive?</option>
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
      <option>4</option>
      <option>6</option>
      <option>7</option>
      <option>8</option>
      <option>9</option>
      <option>10</option>
      <option>11</option>
    </select>
    <br> <br>

    <div class="form-group">
     <input required type="text" class="form-control " id="name" required name="name" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Enter Name">
   </div><br> <br>

   <div class="form-group">   
     <input type="text" class="form-control " id="age" name="age" required  autocomplete="off" placeholder="Enter Age">
   </div> <br> <br>

   <div class="form-group">

     <input type="text" class="form-control " id="depart" name="departLoc" required  autocomplete="off" placeholder="Departure Location">
   </div><br> <br>

   <div class="form-group">

     <input type="text" class="form-control " id="arrive" name="arriveLoc" required  autocomplete="off"placeholder="Destination Location">
   </div><br> <br>

   <div class="form-group">

     <input type="date" class="form-control " id="departDate" name="departDate" required  autocomplete="off"placeholder="Depart Date">
   </div><br> <br>

   <div class="form-group">

     <input type="date" class="form-control " id="returnDate" name="returnDate" autocomplete="off" required placeholder="Return Date">
   </div> <br> <br>
   <div class="form-group">

     <input type="email" class="form-control " id="email" required  name="email" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Email">
   </div><br> <br>
   <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="submitDriver();"> 
 </form>

</div>

</div>


</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#driverbtn').click(function()
    {
        $('#driverForm').toggle();

    });
    $('#riderbtn').click(function()
    {
        $('#riderForm').toggle();
    });

    $('#clearbtn').click(function()
    {
        $.post('clear.php', function()
     {window.location = window.location.href;});

    });




</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready( function(){
    $('#states').ddslick();


  });

</script>



<!--- End of rider data -->




</html>




.driverAlert
{
    color: green;
}
.riderAlert
{
    color:red;
}

body
{
    background-color: white;
}
#allContent div
{

    width: 33%;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}
body
{
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
#riderForm
{

    display: none;

}
#driverForm
{
    display: none;

}

#driverbtn
{
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 22px;
}
#riderbtn
{
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 22px;
}
#rider
{
    position: fixed;
    right: -450px;
}
#driver
{
    position: fixed;
    right: -200px;
}
#options
{
    text-align: center;
}
.trip{
    position: fixed;
    top: 250px;
    right:250px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 16px;
    margin: 10px 0;
    max-width: 468px;
    border: #ddd 1px solid;
    border-top-color: #eee;
    border-bottom-color: #bbb;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
    font: bold 14px/18px Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #000;

}
```

Comment: can you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: We can help you like this. You have many `css` files that we don't know what in there. So, in questions like that, you have to supply a way that we could see what you see (create a snippet/bin, supply public URL) to help you with this.

Comment: I have it online, but the css that impacts the issue I am having is not visible when view page source is clicked since it is applied to php. I can see the css from view page source locally though. Is there anyway around this?